# What is the origin of the term "throw the book"?

Tags: etymology, expressions

I'm curious if "the book" in question is the bible?

Does anyone know where this term first entered the lexicon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not, I think, the Bible, but the law book. The OED’s earliest citation is this from 1932:

> The prosecuting attorney . . . determined to try to get the trial
>   judge to ‘throw the book’ at him

Answer (score 2):

According to [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=%22throw+the+book%22&searchmode=none) the saying dates back to 1932 and refers to a "law book" during sentencing.

> To throw the book at (someone) is 1932, from notion of judge sentencing a criminal from a law book full of possible punishments.

Comment: This etymology is misleadingly worded, even though it is what etymonline says; see my answer to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144290/phraseme-throw-the-book-at).